# How to handle broken pipe error in python? (socket programming)

Tags: python, sockets

In these codes, I'm comparing messages received from clients with text content in a file. When compiled, it works as expected with correct password and username, but with the wrong password, `connection.send(str.encode('Password: '))` will return a broken pipe error. What did I do wrong here?

```
  # user can try 5 times
  while retryCounter < 5:
      if name == check[0] and newPassword != check[1]:
          connection.send(str.encode('> Invalid Password, please try again. \n')) 
          connection.send(str.encode('Password: '))
          newPassword = connection.recv(2048).decode()
          retryCounter = retryCounter + 1
          print(retryCounter)
          if name == check[0] and newPassword == check[1]:
              connection.send(str.encode(f'> Login Successful! \n')) 
              connection.send(str.encode(f'> Welcome to TOOM, {name}.\n'))
              connection.send(str.encode(f'> Enter one of the following commands (MSG, DLT, EDT, RDM, ATU, OUT, UPD):\n'))
              break
          if retryCounter == 4:
              connection.send(str.encode('> You are blocked! '))
```

also the client side code:

```
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# connect the client
client.connect((host, port))
response = client.recv(2048)
# Input UserName
name = input(response.decode()) 
client.send(str.encode(name))
response = client.recv(2048)
# Input Password
password = input(response.decode()) 
client.send(str.encode(password))
''' Response : Status of Connection :
    1 : Registeration successful 
    2 : Login Successful
    3 : Login Failed (wrong password)
'''
# Receive response 
response = client.recv(2048)
response = response.decode()

print(response)
client.close()
```

Comment: Do you understand what it means? Do you expect it to occur in those circumstances?

Comment: It is unclear what the other side actually is (no code or other information). But likely the other side has closed the connection and you are trying to send data on a  connection closed by the peer - which causes the broken pipe error.

Comment: so you mean the client side? i uploaded the client side code, and i think maybe it's because the client's code doesn't have the corresponding for this, could this be the issue? @SteffenUllrich

Answer (score 0):

The server expect the client to retry the password if failed. But the client does not retry the password. Instead the client closes the connection no matter if login was successful or not. When the server asks again for the password it will now write to a socket closed by the client - which will cause Broken Pipe.

The fix is to align the expectations of the server with what the client is actually doing, i.e. either don't expect the client to retry at the server side or actually retry a failed login on the client side.